# How To Perform Specific SELF Join Query SQL

Tags: sql, self-join

I am having a hard time solving this question that I am practicing with.

> Retrieve employee name, designation, and email id of those employees who work in the same retail outlet where George works. Do not display the record of George in the result.

I can solve it with this:

```
SELECT empname, designation, emailid FROM Empdetails WHERE Worksin = (
      SELECT Worksin FROM Empdetails where empname = 'George'
) AND empname <> 'George'
```

But I am trying to figure out how I would use a self join instead of a nested select. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there more fields in the Empdetails table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give the answer by stepping through how you'd make this with images to show each step.

Here is the table I created to give you an example:
[Demo Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGfik.jpg)
(yes, I know I misspelt designation)

---

Let's start off by creating a self join

```
Select *
From EmpDetails A, EmpDetails B
```

Here is the result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyPJL.jpg)

---

Now let's filter the duplicate rows form each table and combine Worksin

```
Select A.empName, A.designation, A.emailId
From EmpDetails A, EmpDetails B
Where A.empName <> B.empName and A.Worksin = B.Worksin
```

Here is the result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opdj5.jpg)

---

Lastly will will filter the empName "George" from the right side (table B) form the data set. This will leave us with George's co-workers. This is also where you select the fields you want to be shown in the last dataset.

```
Select A.empName, A.designation, A.emailId
From EmpDetails A, EmpDetails B
Where A.empName <> B.empName and A.Worksin = B.Worksin and B.empName <> "George"
```

Here is the final table you want: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XzIJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your desired self-join:

```
SELECT ed.empname, ed.designation, ed.emailid 
FROM Empdetails ed inner join Empdetails ed2
     on ed.Worksin = ed2.Worksin and ed2.empname = 'George'
where ed.empname <> 'George';
```